# How to have a variable to take one of some predefined values in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a variable lets say `gender`. I am declaring it in beginning and assigning a value later in the code. I want to restrict the value of `gender` to be either `male` or `female`. Anything other than this should not be accepted (throw an error). Is there a way in typescript to do this?

```
let gender: string;

// some logic here

gender = someFunction();  //Restrict this to only accept 'male' and 'female' as valid values.
```

Comment: make an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums)?

Comment: You should use a union of string literals like `let gender: "male" | "female"`, although then `someFunction()` needs to either be typed to return `"male" | "female"` or the assignment will be a compiler error, at which point you'd need a runtime check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let gender: 'male' | 'female';
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Using Enum

What you can do is to define an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html), and let the return type of your function be that enum. The same goes for your gender variable. It can be of type `Gender` instead of `string`.

```
enum Gender {male, female};

let gender: Gender;

function someFunction(): Gender {
  return Gender.male;
}

// some logic here

gender = someFunction();  //Restrict this to only accept 'male' and 'female' as valid values.
```

#### Using Union Type

As others have mention in their answers, you can also use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). The function also needs to return the same union type.

```
let gender: "male" | "female";

function someFunction(): "male" | "female" {
  return "male";
}

// some logic here

gender = someFunction();  //Restrict this to only accept 'male' and 'female' as valid values.
```

Answer (score 0):

At the variable or constant declaration, you can define the strings it can have, for example

```
let gender: "male" | "female" | "other";
```

You can do the same for typescript interfaces

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For type script I found it convenience to use 'export type ...' . It's a common method found in many libraries. Sample code is as below:

```
export type gender = | 'male' | 'female'
```

Later you can use it in your function like:

```
export function myFunction(input: gender) {
  if (input === 'male') {
     // here input will only accept 'male' or 'female' string
  }
{
```